# Powerpoint "Push" animation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, office365

is there a way to implement a transition between to slides that pushes the next slide in from the bottom, **but keeps the lowest part of the first slide at the top of the second one**? As if it was a big canvas, and the camera would slide downwards.

You can of course use the push transition, but then you'd need the specific element at the bottom of the first slide and the top of the second, and while moving one would see that you have it twice.

Morphing didn't work fine either, because the content of the first slide would obviously disappear and not move upwards out of the visibile area.

Hope you get my question, and sry if its solution is obvious, I'm quite new to PowerPoint.

Comment: This is not an answer for you question, but you might want to check out the **Zoom** feature in Powerpoint. Follow these links: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-zoom-for-powerpoint-to-bring-your-presentation-to-life-9d6c58cd-2125-4d29-86b1-0097c7dc47d7 and  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9T3XX7KWbLU

Comment: To keeps the lowest part of the first slide at the top of the second one, there seems to be no such build-in animation in PowerPoint to do this. You can use Zoom for PowerPoint mentioned in @Gangula 's comment above to have a try. I find the behavior of Pan transition is similar to the Push transition. They don't keep any content of the first slide.

Comment: Thank you too for ur answers :) @HerbGu and Gangula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [kludge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge)

1. Do the layout on both slides like this:

[image]

2. Copy the content of slide 2 onto slide 1 and move it down so that the blue box from slide 2 overlaps the one on slide 1, then delete it (but keep the rest of the content)

[image]

3. Add animation to the blue box so that it moves to the top of the slide, and apply the same animation to all the content of slide 1.

[image]

[image]

If everything is lined up properly, once the animation has played, the slide transition will be invisible.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! Not only has that solved my issue (although I wonder if this will be worth the work on a regular basis), but also given me great insight in the animation functionality of Powerpoint. ty :)